# How to take the value of an Angular select each time it changes?

Tags: angular, html-select, onchange

I have this code in my html

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
          <mat-select (change)="selectOpt($event)" required formControlName="country">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.name" >
              {{country.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

How can I take the value of the select each time something different is selected? I have the (change) event in my mat-select but it doesn't catch the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change for `(selectionChange)="selectOpt($event)"` and it will work